# Symfony 4 form from yaml not found

Tags: symfony, yaml

How i can generate form from yaml file in symfony 4
I found this bundle but comppatible just with symfony 3
https://github.com/LinioIT/dynamic-form-bundle

Answer (score 0):

Symfony don't provide a way to declare forms in `yaml` format.

So if you really want to use it, you can ask in an issue on the https://github.com/LinioIT/dynamic-form-bundle if an update compatibility is a plan.

If not you can contribute by doing a PR and make the bundle compatible `Symfony 4`

No simple solution in your case because you aren't following the good practices of Symfony.

Why do you want absolutely use `YAML` format?